# What is a makefile exactly and how we can create one?

Tags: makefile

I know this is a silly question, but since I am trying so hard to learn linux by myself, I need some help from you fellows.

I found this task on the internet and I am trying to solve it but I don't understand exactly how can I use makefiles in linux and how can I create them.

Let's suppose my print working directory is `/home/george/Documents`

I want to create a makefile which does the following:

1. Displays a message as follows "hello work, today is Sun". Sun comes from Sunday. So I must use `date` command in this make file to display just first three letters.
2. compress `/etc/hosts` in `/tmp` using `gzip` (probably here should be something like

   ```
   gzip -c SOURCE DESTINATION # ??
   ```

Cheers

Comment: Makefiles are there to selectively build outdated object files from source files, in a software development activity. It has nothing to do to what you would do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to answer your question I cant give you a one line / paragraph answer because it deals with every thing.Read **the first link** it have everything you need with examples too.

Good tutorial that can explain everything about make

- http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/create_makefile.1.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/make.1.html

Comment: the first link should be : http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/

Comment: [mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/) tutorial uses outdated c++ code and no longer compiles. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103108/why-cant-g-find-iostream-h) to understand and fix.

Comment: Links are dead .

Answer (score 3):

A Makefile is used as a "map" for C programs compilation. They work with the `make` utility, an describe how a program has to be compiled/linked in order to work correctly once turned into a executable file. For global UNIX/shell tasks, you're looking for shell scripts, not makefiles :)

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefiles for more information about makefiles, and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script to discover shell scripts.

A basic shell script for what you're trying to do could be :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world, today is $(date +%a)"
gzip -c SOURCE DESTINATION
```

Store this in a file, and execute it using your shell prompt (`bash myscript.sh`, `sh myscript.sh`, ...). You can also make the script executable using :

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

And then execute it with your default interpretor with :

```
./myscript.sh
```

Comment: I am trying to create a makefile which does this not a shell script.

Comment: Then you have to develop a C program which does this, and compile it using a Makefile, if you want. Makefiles **do not** execute Linux tasks, they guide C programs compilation, it is a completely different thing.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith There is **nothing** special about compiling C programs. Makefiles *can* be used to perform a variety of tasks. (With that said, many tasks are poorly suited for the use of makefiles.)

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a shell script, then create a symbolic link that points to the shell script you created?  Place the symbolic link in a directory that's in the PATH, so that you can 'run' the symbolic link no matter the directory in which you are located.