# Compiling C codes in Ubuntu

Tags: compiling, gcc, c

I'm a rookie programmer and trying to compile a C code in Ubuntu. I already installed GCC. How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 7):

You can compile from following command :

```
$ gcc -o object-file C-source-file
```

Then try to run :

```
$ ./object-file
```

For C code you can use `cc` command too also you can use `g++` for C++.

Once your code becomes more complicated and you start using more and more files, the above will become cumbersome and you'll want to [look into "makefiles"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333786/what-is-a-makefile-exactly-and-how-we-can-create-one). They work for small projects too, so the sooner you become familiar with them, the better. If you later code in C++, you will also likely use these.

Answer (score 0):

or you [can compile](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Compiling) your f.c file from console:

```
gcc f.c -Wall
```

then run :

```
./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open one):

1. Change the directory to where you have saved the .c file using

   ```
   cd path
   ```

   command
2. Type the following command and change the `fileName` with yours

   ```
   gcc -o c-fileName fileName.c
   ```

   You can write any name instead of c-fileName.
3. Then to run your file type

   ```
   ./c-fileName
   ```

   in terminal.

Comment: Shouldn't `c-fileName` go directly after the `-o`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry, for the typo error.

Comment: For every level of indentation, code blocks require four more spaces. In this case, you have one level of indentation with the numbered list, so you need eight spaces.