# Can't run my hello world in C

Tags: gcc, c

I'm trying to write a basic program in C using gedit or sublime text (which I prefer), but no matter what I do when I try to compile or run, or even while writing, I have no option to use 'stdio.h' or any similar package.
Even when I start typing `#include <st` the only word completion sublime suggests is 'struct'.

I've read dozens of threads, but all managed to fix this by installing `gcc`, which I've tried to reinstall multiple times, with no luck.

This is the output from `gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) `
```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

When I compile using `gcc`, I get nothing, no error at least.
but when I try to run using just `./hello.c` this is what I get.

Comment: You don't run the `hello.c` file - you run the executable file that's produced by running `gcc` **on** the `hello.c` file

Comment: jesus how could I do such a stupid mistake... noober than i thought. anyway, do you know why text editors wont recognize the libraries?

Comment: A text editor is just a text editor - it's not like a dedicated IDE (that might be programmed to complete filenames) - although some (including `gedit`)  may offer [syntax highlighting](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-syntax-highlighting.html.en)

Comment: It isn't a stupid mistake, it's just that you weren't aware. This is part of the learning process, though it often comes (as per my own experience back in the day) from skipping through learning material instead of paying close attention to it. There will very likely be plugins for Sublime Text to help with recognising libraries, so keep an eye out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling C codes in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951736/compiling-c-codes-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Don't worry, I made exactly the same mistake when I first learned to write C. It isn't obvious at first what the compiler outputs, but now you can go on and make a tonne of brand new mistakes. Welcome to programming...

Comment: Btw, nothing wrong with Sublime Text, but industry generally uses the free [Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/). Use whichever you prefer, but learn about setting breakpoints; these will allow you to run your code and stop at any line you mark as a breakpoint, then examine & change variable values, look at the call stack, to see which function called which, called ... and with which parameters. You can then step through your code a line at a time, if you want to.

Comment: When you code gives problems, ask at [StackOVerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to 1) post your code 2) say what it is supposed to do 3) describe what it is doing wrongly. If you do that, people can help you

Comment: And also, be aare of our [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. you can post ***working*** code there and others will read it an recommend ways to improve it. This can help make you a better coder. If you don't want to post your own code, read other people's reviews. Try reading & understanding the code first, before you read the suggestions for improvement. Soon you will be able to make suggestions.

Comment: @Mawg: That depends on which subset of "industry" you mean. The subset using Eclipse CDT does, of course. Personally, I've never met a person (online or offline) using Eclipse regularly; instead, they used some text editor (Sublime, Emacs, vi, Notepad++, SciTe, pico), some shell (most often bash), and gcc or ICC, or an IDE like MSVC (despite not being a fully compliant C environment), Code::Blocks or something. But that's just my own humble experience which I stated for the lack of a representative statistics search result.

Comment: Well, my subset is professional embedded developers. Obviously, YMMV, but I would be very surprised if any respectable employer required, or even allowed, its employees to use a plain text editor, rather than an IDE with an integrated debugger. I am  aware of the others, and have used most of them in my day. I am personally very fond of [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/), which you omitted to mention.

Comment: I don't think that it really matters, just so long as an IDE with integrated debugger is used, but in a  few decades of freelancing on three continents, I can't remember the last embedded coding gig that did not use Eclipse. Anyway, let's not argue, I hope that you will also recommend the OP, who his just starting out, to use an IDE with integrated debugger.

Comment: you can't run `./hello.c` but just `./hello`, which is the compiled file that has to be executed.

Answer (score 39):

gcc creates an executable file called a.out by default. Run that instead.

Alternatively, create a sensible named executable:

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
```

And even simpler, using the [default rules built into make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

```
make hello
```

Comment: And who will write Makefile?!

Comment: You don't have to have a makefile to use make! Try it and see...

Comment: Great, it really works.

Comment: I've updated my answer to link to the relevant part of the Gnu make documentation

Comment: for me it returns : make: Nothing to be done for 'init.c'.

Comment: @Sketch, what exactly did you type?

Comment: My bad, ran now, awesome tip, thank you very much for your aid mate.

Comment: +1 Awesome trivia about make. I learned something new today

Answer (score 11):

You need to install the corresponding package with the headers (normally `libc6-dev`) with

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
```

And for sure install `build-essential` with

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then compile your `hello.c` with the command:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
```

and run it:

```
./hello
```

Comment: I think i installed those a thousand times. but the last part, someone already commented it, worked. thanks!